Compute the integral: $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}J_{0}(x)dx$
At first, I was computing the following integral: $$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}J_0(\sqrt{x})dx$$ which can be easily solved using the taylor series of $J_0(x)$:
$$J_0(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{4^n(n!)^2}$$
The reason why this integral is easier to solve is because of that square root of $x$, simplifying the sum with gamma function and into a basic taylor series, giving the answer $\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{e}}$.
But then, WolframAlpha challenged me with a similar integral but without the square root inside and now I'm having trouble solving the integral with Taylor Series.
Is there a nice elementary or a sneaky way to compute this integral?

We will use the generalized binomial theorem, we have the fact that
$$\binom{2n}{n} = (-4)^n\binom{-1/2}{n}.$$
Now we continue by using the series for $J_0$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty e^{-x}J_0(x)dx &= \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^n}{4^n(n!)^2}\int_0^\infty e^{x}x^{2n}dx = \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^n}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\\
&= \sum_{n \geq 0} \binom{-1/2}{n}(1)^n = (1 + 1)^{-1/2} = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.
\end{align}
